# Owner and Co-owner of Groups

Tags: c#, active-directory

I want to write an c# application which will fetch the Active Directiry group names of which the currently logged in user is owner/co-owner.

In our environment, we add the owner in managed by tab of the group and co-owner is added to security tab of the group and  is given write security permissions.

I can the fetch the groups of which the user is owner through the managed objects user attribute in AD, but there is no provision to fetch the co-owner.

Please let me know if there is any attribute through which i can get the group names of which the user is co-owner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not a way to query AD based on the ACL. You'd need to scan through every group and inspect the ACLs. If you have Exchange, it has an attribute for managing multiple owners (msExchCoManagedBy or similar), or, you could extend your AD schema with a similar multiple owners attribute to search on.